# How to get this printer working in Windows 7 over a network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, printer

Here is the setup:

**Router**

- Windows XP 32-bit
- Windows 7 64-bit

The XP machine has a Lexmark printer physically attached. I have installed the x64 drivers for the printer installed in Windows 7. When I try to print to the printer on the Windows 7 machine, it doesn't work - I get an error:

```
Windows cannot connect to the printer. Error 0x0000000d
```

I have made sure UDP/TCP ports 135-139 are unblocked on the Windows 7 machine.

Comment: search around; there are several questions about this same type of thing on Super User already, eg http://superuser.com/questions/142510/cant-add-a-network-printer-windows-7 and http://superuser.com/questions/97718/printer-sharing-problem-win7-winxp-canon-pixma-usb-printer ... not sure which if any this question is a duplicate of, but one of them may fit and have a good answer for you.

Comment: @quack: Thanks, but they aren't *exactly* the same problem.

Comment: i didn't say they were; i said there are several similar questions and you should search around.  i'm actually quite positive you'll find one that is *exactly* the same problem, but i haven't had time to search and find it myself.  good luck with your question.

Comment: poor quack...  always getting picked on ;--)

Answer (score 1):

I find that although installing drivers can fix this type of problem, sometimes actually using the installation disc that came with the hardware works best.  I would try to install the drivers from the disc.  Load the software on the disc onto each machine on the network (if possible).

Comment: The disc only has x86 drivers though. Nothing for x64.